# How to setup a optional or conditional formControlName?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

LongStoryShort :

I am looking for a way to have the ability to add / fill or not the property'formControlName based on some condition. A null / empty string value would be fine for me, but Angular will not allow me to do so.

More informations :
I created some custom form components, which contains native HTML form elements.
I would like to use those components with or without ReactiveForms so I need to be able to specify a formControlName property or not. When i need to use ReactiveForms, I will just add a FormGroup in the parent calling my Components. It is already working because I used :

`viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }].`

I just need to solve the conditional formControlName property thing.

Here what I already tried :

```
<input [formControlName]="(isSomething) ? 'my-name' : ''" />
<input [formControlName]="(isSomething) ? 'my-name' : null" />
<input [formControlName]="(isSomething) ? 'my-name' : false" />
```

Doesnt work : Angular yells at me.

`<input [attr.formControlName]="" />`

Doesnt work : render with a formcontrolname="" (in lowercase, and ignored by FormGroup)

In order to achieve the very same goal, is it possible to add or not a property based on a condition ?

```
<input
  id="stuff-1"
  class="stuff"
  (cond === true) [formControlName]="my-name" // only if condition is true
  (cond === false) // do nothing
/>
```

I also tried with a custom directive but not clue how to make it work.
Only option I found is to have an `*ngIf` on a container and two separate inputs...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="false">
  <input
     id="stuff-1"
     class="stuff"
  />
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <input
    id="stuff-1"
    class="stuff"
    [formControlName]="name"
  />
</ng-container>
```

EDIT : After some hours of wandering, I realize that I should just put (or not) [formControlName]="xxx" directly on my CustomFormElementComponent, and fire a  (input)="changeFormElementValue(#element.value)" on the input native Html element present in my CustomFormElementComponent (which implements ControlValueAccessor).

Answer (score 2):

It may be an overkill, but you might consider a directive like this:

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appConditionalName]',
  standalone: true
})
export class ConditionalNameDirective {
  @Input() readonly appConditionalName: string = '';
  @Input('condition') readonly condition: boolean = false;

  constructor(
        private readonly viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.condition) {
      const el = this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;

      el.setAttribute('formControlName', this.appConditionalName);
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<input appConditionalName="firstName" [condition]="condition" />
```

See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/conditional-formcontrolname

Comment: Hey Benny, tysm for your reply. That's exactly what I was trying to do with the directive, but I think it is a deadend. setAttribute() lowercase everything so it doesn't work. I edited my first post, I may have found another way to take.

Comment: @rou6e I don't think lowercase is a problem. Check the rendered markup (in devtools) of `<input formControlName="firstName" />`. I think Angular renders lowercase too

Comment: I digged/adapted your code to my needs and I can confirm that `formControlName` is added (lowercase) based on condition, so cheers for that ! I confirm that Angular renders it in lowercase too, BUT I think it does not really work because the use of the dynamic formControlName doesnt trigger the error normally fired when used outside a `<form [formGroup]>`. And I seem to not being able to manage the field (inside a formGroup) with my FormBuilder. AFAIK, this is exactly the same problem as using [attr.formControlName]. Finally, I do confirm my last EDIT in OP. Anyway tysm for your time.

Comment: Admittedly I did not code a full example with form builder. I solely  focused on the directive